# Scrapy not collecting data

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

i am using scrapy to collect some emails from craiglist and when i run it it returns blank row in .csv file. I am able to extract title,tag and link. Only email is the problem. Here is the code:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


# item class included here
class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    link = scrapy.Field()
    attr = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    tag = scrapy.Field()

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://raleigh.craigslist.org/bab/5038434567.html"
    ]

    BASE_URL = 'http://raleigh.craigslist.org/'

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a[@class="hdrlnk"]/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            absolute_url = self.BASE_URL + link
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_attr)

    def parse_attr(self, response):
        match = re.search(r"(\w+)\.html", response.url)
        if match:
            item_id = match.group(1)
            url = self.BASE_URL + "reply/nos/vgm/" + item_id

            item = DmozItem()
            item["link"] = response.url
            item["title"] = "".join(response.xpath("//span[@class='postingtitletext']//text()").extract())
            item["tag"] = "".join(response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract()[0])
            return scrapy.Request(url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_contact)

    def parse_contact(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item["attr"] = "".join(response.xpath("//div[@class='anonemail']//text()").extract())
        return item
```

Comment: The default callback function when starting with `start_urls` is `parse()`, not `parse_contact()`. Also, there is no emails in that URL defined in `start_urls`, so your xpath doesn't match anything. Did you read through the [Scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)? These things are explained there.

Comment: This code worked for me so far but last two days it seems that something is modified on the craiglist. Can you please add working code? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ArkanKalu you need to provide the complete code of your spider.

Comment: @alecxe Sure, here you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you meant to have `start_urls` at the catalog page: `http://raleigh.craigslist.org/search/bab`.

Also, from what I understand, the additional request to get an email should go to `reply/ral/bab/` instead of `reply/nos/vgm/`.

Also, if there is no attr group, you are getting an error on the following line:

```
item["tag"] = "".join(response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract()[0])
```

Replace it with:

```
item["tag"] = "".join(response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract())
```

The complete code that worked for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import scrapy


class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    link = scrapy.Field()
    attr = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    tag = scrapy.Field()


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["raleigh.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://raleigh.craigslist.org/search/bab"
    ]

    BASE_URL = 'http://raleigh.craigslist.org/'

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a[@class="hdrlnk"]/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            absolute_url = self.BASE_URL + link
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_attr)

    def parse_attr(self, response):
        match = re.search(r"(\w+)\.html", response.url)
        if match:
            item_id = match.group(1)
            url = self.BASE_URL + "reply/ral/bab/" + item_id

            item = DmozItem()
            item["link"] = response.url
            item["title"] = "".join(response.xpath("//span[@class='postingtitletext']//text()").extract())
            item["tag"] = "".join(response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract())
            return scrapy.Request(url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_contact)

    def parse_contact(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item["attr"] = "".join(response.xpath("//div[@class='anonemail']//text()").extract())
        return item
```

Comment: Thanks code works fine! How can i limit scrapy to extract 50 rows?

Comment: @ArkanKalu you are welcome, let's not solve new problems in comments, consider creating a separate question if you have difficulties. Thanks.